# How do I iterate through an array of nils?

Tags: ruby, iteration, null

I'm trying to set up an Array with all nil values so that someone can iterate the sequence for each value until it reaches the end, then displays the changed array.

```rb
class Big
  def ben
    x = [nil,1,nil,2]
    y = 0
    x[y] == nil ? "good": "bad"
    y += 1
    puts x
  end
end
```

I know this can be simplified. Is there a way to overwrite each value in the array?

Comment: Your code sample isn't complete. Please show how you are calling the `ben` method, and what the expected output is. As is, it looks like a very contrived example that doesn't do anything.

Comment: You are very right. I forgot to call the method therefor it is incomplete. Sorry to give not complete the code.                       It should call as `Big.new.ben` is what I was calling it as.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that might help, based on what I see in the sample code.

This is a simple way to create an array if you want it to be a certain size filled with `nil` values:

```
foo = [nil] * 5
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

If you want to interweave two arrays, such as an array of nils and another one with values:

```
TOTAL_ELEMENTS = 5

([nil] * TOTAL_ELEMENTS).zip((1..TOTAL_ELEMENTS).to_a).flatten
=> [nil, 1, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil, 5]
```

---

Based on the OPs comment below, that this is for a tic-tac-toe game, here are some ways to create `x`:

```
Array.new(9)
[nil] * 9
```

Both of which return:

```
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

That is useful if you receive the cell coordinate as an offset from 0.

For a tic-tac-toe grid it might be more useful to have three rows of three columns if you get your cell coordinates as an row/column pair:

```
Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
[[nil] * 3] * 3
```

Returning:

```
=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

And some things to meditate on:

```
ROWS = COLUMNS = 3

x = Array.new( ROWS * COLUMNS )            # for offsets
x = Array.new(ROWS) { Array.new(COLUMNS) } # for rows and columns
```

If you get your position as an offset but want to convert it to a row/column,
use `divmod`. Your offset will be 0..8, being converted to fit into a 3x3 grid, 
i.e. `[0..2][0..2]`. Converting back is easy too:

```
def row_col_to_offset(x,y)
  x * ROW + y
end  
>> row_col_to_offset(0,0) # => 0
>> row_col_to_offset(0,1) # => 1
>> row_col_to_offset(1,1) # => 4
>> row_col_to_offset(2,2) # => 8

def offset_to_row_col(o)
  o.divmod(ROW)
end  
>> offset_to_row_col(0) # => [0, 0]
>> offset_to_row_col(1) # => [0, 1]
>> offset_to_row_col(4) # => [1, 1]
>> offset_to_row_col(8) # => [2, 2]
```

Now you need to learn about Ruby's `@` instance variables, and the proper use of the `initialize` method.

Comment: I find `[nil] * 5`, a peculiar way of doing `Array.new(5)`, but the result is the same...

Comment: Maybe I was a little unclear as to what I wanted to get at. I am doing a tictactoe in which a user will select a number from an array 0..8 `    x= [nil,nil,nil]` then user 1 selects 0 `x = [nil, "X", nil]` then user 2 selects 2 `x = [nil, "x", "O"]`

Comment: Do you have to use a single array of nine elements, or can you use three arrays of three elements, i.e., `x[0..2][0..2]`?

Comment: @Thrillr, I added some more things that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right you could do this:

```rb
class Big 
  def ben
    x = [nil,1,nil,2]
    # These lines don't do much
    # y = 0
    # x[y] == nil ? "good": "bad"
    # y += 1
    puts x
  end
end
```

And yes to your second question: [`fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-fill). For example:

```rb
[1, 2, 3].fill(0) # => [0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It would be good to explain why it is OK to comment-out the intermediate lines in the `ben` method. The OP might not understand why.